# How to Re-Create Missing Vim Directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

The `/etc/vim` directory and the symlinks from `/usr/share/vim` to it are missing. Does anyone know how to re-create the directory and links?

Answer (score 3):

Un-install and re-install the Vim package.